# How to reference styles properly in InDesign Scripting?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I would like to know what is the proper way to reference a character style, a paragraph style or any other style in InDesign Scripting.

Please keep in mind that they could be under style group.

Comment: It depends. If you know in advance if, and in what group, it's a straightforward set of `paragraphStyleGroup`: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/892883. If you don't know if or in what group a named style is, you'll have to scan them all (and decide on a strategy for re-used style names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took an approach where you have to work with what I call the Fully Qualified Name (FQN) of a style, which is combination of all the groups and the style name separated by a pipe (|)

I've implemented the two following function in our code.  They can be used with all type of styles with just a little bit of modification to the getStyleByFullyQualifiedName() function to support the other 4 types.

```js
//getStyleFullyQualifiedName allow you to retrieve the style FQN,
//by providing a style object. Combine the name of the style and
//groups together separated by pipe (|).
function getStyleFullyQualifiedName(object){
    var objectName = object.name;

    if(object.parent.constructor.name != "Document"){
        return getStyleFullyQualifiedName(object.parent) + "|" + objectName;
    }

    return objectName;
}

function getStyleByFullyQualifiedName(paragraphStyleFQN, document){
    var tmp = paragraphStyleFQN.split("|");

    var object = document;

    for(var i=0; i < (tmp.length - 1); i++){
        if(object.isValid){
            object = object.paragraphStyleGroups.itemByName(tmp[i]);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    if(!object.isValid){
        return null;
    }

    object = object.paragraphStyles.itemByName(tmp[(tmp.length - 1)]);

    if(!object.isValid){
        return null;
    }

    return object;
}

//Assuming you have a style "Heading 1" under group "Title" and "Center.
//You can retrieve the style object like this.
var styleObject = getStyleByFullyQualifiedName("Title|Center|Heading 1", app.activeDocument);

//You can get the style FQN when you have a style object like this.
var styleFQN = getStyleFullyQualifiedName(styleObject);

alert("Valid: " + styleObject.isValid + " styleFQN: " + styleFQN);
```

Comment: Nice -- a pretty useful function! To make it fool-proof, you might want to throw in an `isValid` check inside the loop and return `null` if this fails. (For a possibly more efficient implementation you could use `tmp.shift()` until the `tmp` array is empty. Just a thought, though.)

Comment: Jong, I took your advise and added conditions to make sure the objects are valid. I don't like the look of it right now and I might get back to it and rewrite it with the shift() method eventually.  Maybe I'm just been too picky. :D

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. Have a look at the function get_style.

#### update: use id instead of names

```
// written for
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302941/how-to-reference-styles-properly-in-indesign-scripting
// author: @fabiantheblind
// license: wtfpl http://www.wtfpl.net
main();
function main(){
var doc = app.documents.add();// add a document

// create some styles
doc.paragraphStyles.add({name:"one"});
doc.paragraphStyles.add({name:"two"});
doc.paragraphStyles.add({name:"three"});
// add a group
var grp1 = doc.paragraphStyleGroups.add({name:"grp1"});
// add a style in the group
grp1.paragraphStyles.add({name:"four"});
// add a group in the group
var grp2 = grp1.paragraphStyleGroups.add({name:"grp2"});
// add a style in the group in the group
var parstylefive = grp2.paragraphStyles.add({name:"five"});
var fiveid = parstylefive.id;

var pg = doc.pages[0];// first page in new doc
var tf=  pg.textFrames.add({geometricBounds:[0,0,100,100]});// add a textframe
    tf.contents = TextFrameContents.PLACEHOLDER_TEXT;// add some cintent


var astyle = get_style(doc, fiveid);//get a style by name

    if(astyle === null){
        // error
          alert("There is no style with that name");
        }else{
          // woohoo! \o/
          tf.paragraphs.everyItem().appliedParagraphStyle = astyle;
        }

}

/**
 * This loops through all paragraph styles and returns one by his name
 *  could be rewritten for allCharacterStyles, allObjectStyles etc
 */
function get_style(d, id){
    var thestyle = null;// result

    for(var i = 0; i <d.allParagraphStyles.length;i++ ){

        var onestyle = d.allParagraphStyles[i]; // isolate
        if(id === onestyle.id){
            thestyle = onestyle;// found it
            } // end of check
        } // end of loop i
    // if we did not finds it we return null else Object ParagraphStyle
    return thestyle;
    }
```

Comment: I understand that, in fact this is how we are doing it right now in our script, but using this method involve having unique names for each styles, if not you'll always get the first or last match like in your code sample.

Comment: Why not use doc.paragraphStyles.itemByID (or itemByName)?

Comment: @fabianmoronzirfas: like
astyle = document.allParagraphStyles.itemByName("five");
astyle = document.allParagraphStyles.itemByID(fiveid);
[http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_ParagraphStyles.html#itemByID]

Comment: Maybe add an answer to the question? So future searches will have better answers.